# Need help calculating number of possible passwords with given criteria

Tags: permutations

I need help calculating the number of possible passwords with a given set of criteria. Here is the set of criteria:

- Passwords are case insensitive.
- Must be 6-14 characters.
- Must contain at least 1 letter and 1 number.
- Must not be equivalent to your current or 3 previous passwords.
- May not contain 9 or more numbers.
- May not be identical to your Username.
- May not repeat the same number or letter more than 3 times in a row.
- May not contain more than 3 sequential numbers or letters (such as '1234' or 'abcd') in a row.
- May contain special characters (such as @, %, &, #).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any thoughts of your own?

Comment: Well, most of those criteria are limiting the number of possible passwords. I would start by taking how many possible 6-letter password, 7-letter password, ... , 14-letter password combos there are, and then whittling down the result using the criteria.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I understand that that's what I have to do. I'm just not sure how to calculate some of the criteria, such as..."May not repeat the same number or letter more than 3 times in a row." or "May not contain more than 3 sequential numbers or letters (such as '1234' or 'abcd') in a row."